# Перевод с SQL Developer на PostgerSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, plsql-developer, sqldeveloper

Дали задание перенести VIEWs c Oracle на PostgerSQL:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -46) + LEVEL  AS date_value
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TRUNC (SYSDATE) - ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -46)
```

Выдает результат от даты которая была 46 месяцев назад до сегодняшней.
Начал разбираться какие есть схожие функции в PosgreSQL, нашел что можно записать такой запрос:

```
select now()
```

Он выдаст сегодняшнюю дату и время. И собственно говоря вопрос, как сделать так чтобы он еще и выдавал даты на 46 месяцев назад от сегодняшней, нигде не могу найти что-то похожее.

Comment: На PostgreSQL нужно писАть рекурсивный CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам просто надо вывести дату каждого месяца от нынешней даты до 46
месяцев назад, вы можете просто использовать
`generate_series`:

```sql
SELECT date
  FROM generate_series(
         NOW()
       , NOW() - INTERVAL '46 months'
       , - INTERVAL '1 month'
       ) AS dates(date)
;
```